# Am I able to use normal plain java class with Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I know we can use a `case class` as the type parameter of the Slick `Table` defination like this:

```scala
case class User(id:Option[Int], name:Option[String])

class TestUserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = (id.?, name.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
val users = lifted.TableQuery[TestUserTable]
```

But the reality for one of my recent project is there already has a lot of old java plant classes as the data model has been defined, for example there is a `User` class is pre-defined already:

```java
public class User() {
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to transparently transfer these classes to any forms so that they can be accessed by the Table definition without re-implemented?

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes.

Given a Java class like:

```java
public class User {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  public User(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Integer getId() { return id; }
  public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

A Slick table definition could look like

```scala
class TestUserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = ???
}
```

What to replace the `???` with?  With an understanding of what

```scala
(id.?, name.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
```

does, it will hopefully become clear.

- `id.?` and `name.?` basically convert the `Rep` to a `Rep[Option]` (viz. `column[Int]` to a `column[Option[Int]]`), so `(id.?, name.?)` is a `Tuple2[Rep[Option[Int]], Rep[Option[String]]]`
- `User.tupled` desugars to `(User.apply _).tupled`, so it's (in this case) a function with type: `Tuple2[Option[Int], Option[String]] => User`
- `User.unapply` desugars to `User.unapply _`, so it's a function with type `User => Option[Tuple2[Option[Int], Option[String]]]`
- The `<>` operation (added by Slick) on a `Tuple2[Rep[A], Rep[B]]` applied to a `Tuple2[Tuple2[A, B] => C, C => Option[Tuple2[A, B]]]` results in the code which projects `C`s to a DB row containing an `A` and a `B` and vice versa.

So that means it's sufficient to define functions which match the signatures.  In this case:

- given a tuple of an `Option[Int]` and an `Option[String]` return a [Java] `User`
- given a [Java] `User` return an `Option[(Option[Int], Option[String])]`

and we can use those functions in place of `User.tupled` and `User.unapply`.

For example:

```scala
object TestUserTable {
  val toUser = { tup: (Option[Int], Option[String]) =>
    val (id, name) = tup
    new User(id.orNull, name.orNull)
  }

  val fromUser: User => Option[(Option[Int], Option[String])] = { user =>
    val idOpt = Option(user.getId())
    val nameOpt = Option(user.getName())

    Some((idOpt, nameOpt))  // could also, since there's only 2, write Some(idOpt -> nameOpt)
  }
}
```

And then have

```scala
def * = (id.?, name.?) <> (TestUserTable.toUser, TestUserTable.fromUser)
```

Comment: Thank you @Levi for the very clear explanation! this solution does work, there's only one very little thing was missing which is the conversion from Int to java Integer in `new User(id.orNull, name.orNull)` but an implicit conversion can fix. Very impressive!